# Migrating opencart 1.5.6 to 3.0.2.0 will affect seo?

Tags: seo, opencart

I have an website https://www.elisfashion.ro on opencart 1.5.6.

Now I'm working on www2.elisfashion.ro on opencart 3.0.2.0, which is in development now. When will be done, I will transfer my database with all my products/categories/orders etc.

When www2 will be done, will become www.

I will have same seo url for categories/products, but will be a different opencart version, with a different theme.

So this will affect my seo ? Currently I have 300-400 unique visitors from organic. I will lose those visitors ?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions are off topic as the tag says.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.5.6 version the seo url keywords were saved in 
url_alias table
Now in 3 Version its saved in
seo_url
So you need to import the data from url_alias to seo_url and this way you will not loose seo urls.
Only condition is the product_id and category id match from previous installation to new opencart 3 version.